# $H-\Lambda H \Lambda > 0$ if $H>0$ and $\mathbf{0}_n<\Lambda<\mathbf{1}_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $H>0$ be a $(n\times n)$-positive definite Hermitian matrix. Let $\mathbf{0}_n<\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}<\mathbf{1}_n$ be a diagonal matrix with entries $0<\lambda_j<1\,(1\leq j \leq n)$. Then can we say that $H-\Lambda H \Lambda > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in general is no and you can see this by tackling an easier problem and wielding continuity.

First I assume $H$ is not diagonal, and then fix some selection of $\mathbf{0}_n<\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\}<\mathbf{1}_n$  now define
$\Lambda' :=\{1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$

---

*technical nit:*
if column 1 of $H$ is propotional to the 1st std basis vector, then instead 'attack' column $j$ which is not proportional to $\mathbf e_j$ and do this by instead selecting
$\Lambda' :=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{j-1},1,\lambda_{j+1},\ldots,\lambda_n\}$. Since $H$ is not diagonal, it is easiest to just assume WLOG that column 1 of $H$ has at least 2 non-zero components-- and the argument here tacitly does this.

---

Then
$\big(H-\Lambda' H \Lambda'\big)$
is a Hermitian matrix with a zero in the top left corner but that first column is non-zero, hence the matrix is not positive semi-definite.  (i.e. it necessarily has mixed *signature*).   Finally for $\tau \in [0,1]$ define
$\Lambda(\tau):= \tau \cdot \Lambda + (1-\tau)\cdot \Lambda '$

By topological continuity of eigenvalues
$\Big(H-\Lambda(\tau) H \Lambda(\tau)\Big)$ is not positive semi-definite for $\tau \in [0,\delta)$ for some $\delta \gt 0$. And setting e.g. $\tau:= \frac{\delta}{2}$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I was wondering however, that can we say something about the bounds on eigenvalues of $\Lambda H \Lambda$ here? Suppose we start from $\Lambda^2<\mathbf{1}_n$. Then $H^{1/2}\Lambda^2 H^{1/2}<H$. Now as eigenvalues of $H^{1/2}\Lambda^2 H^{1/2}=(H^{1/2}\Lambda)(\Lambda H^{1/2})$ are the same as those of $(\Lambda H^{1/2})(H^{1/2}\Lambda)=\Lambda H \Lambda$, can we say that the ordered eigenvalues of $\Lambda H \Lambda$ are less than the ordered eigenvalues of $H$?

Comment: It seems that you have different question now as your follow-up-- for Hermitian PD matrices $A$, $B$ where $A-B \succeq \mathbf 0$ can we say the ordered eigenvalues of $A$ (weakly) dominate those of $B$?  The answer is yes though it takes some work.  I gave a proof via Cauchy Interlacing here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246815/edit-a-question-on-eigenvalues-of-non-negative-matrices/4247059#4247059 .