# For reversible Markov chains larger off diagonal elements imply smaller eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

The following is claimed in Remark 3.1 in [this](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/metrop.pdf) paper (page 6). Let $M$ and $M'$ be $\pi$-reversible Markov chains on $X$ with eigenvalues $1=\lambda_0 \ge \lambda_1 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_{|X|-1}$ and $1=\lambda_0' \ge \lambda_1' \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_{|X|-1}'$, respectively. Assume that $M'(x,y) \le M(x,y)$ for all $x \neq y$. Then, for all $i$, $\lambda_i \le \lambda_i'$.

In the paper, it says that this follows from the minimax characterization of eigenvalues. Why does this follow from the minimax characterization? Is this an immediate consequence of it?

I would appreciate any help or reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is actually a collection of results.  I assume both chains are irreducible.  Consider the matrix

**1.)** $\big(M'-M\big)$
this has $\mathbf 1$ in its kernel, with non-negative entries on the diagonal and non-positive entries on the off diagonal.  By Gerschgorin Discs, all eigenvalues of $\big(M'-M\big)$ have non-negative real parts.

**2.)** since they are both $\pi$-invariant and reversible, they have the same stationary distribution and are both similar to real symmetric matrices $S'$ and $S$ via the same diagonal matrix $D^\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $S' = D^\frac{1}{2}M'D^\frac{-1}{2}$ and  $S = D^\frac{1}{2}MD^\frac{-1}{2}$.  Then $\big(S'-S\big)\succeq \mathbf 0$  because $\big(S'-S\big)$ is a real symmetric matrix with no negative eigenvalues by (1).  For more information on $D$ ref [If $P$ is the transition matrix of a reversible Markov chain, why are its eigenvalues real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/3524002#3524002)

**3.)** $\big(S'-S\big)\succeq \mathbf 0\iff S'\succeq S$ and this implies the eigenvalues of $S'$ weakly dominate those of $S$.  In other words $\lambda_i'\geq \lambda_i$ for $i \in \big\{1,2,...,n\big\}$ since by similarity $M'$ and $S'$ must have the same eigenvalues and also $M$ and $S$ must have the same eigenvalues by similarity.  I suppose you could prove the dominance relation via min-max characterization, though I prefer looking at it via Cauchy Interlacing; I gave a proof here.
[EDIT: A question on eigenvalues of non-negative matrices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246815/edit-a-question-on-eigenvalues-of-non-negative-matrices/4247059#4247059)

Comment: Got it, thanks for the great answer!